# User input in git pre-receive hook

Tags: git

So instead of putting ACLs in a git pre-receive hook, I just want to put a confirmation message (y/n) to anyone pushing into the master branch (which happens to be my release branch as well) of my project.

Something like this works for a client side hook, but I'm unsure of how to achieve this on server side:

```
while true; do
  read -p "[pre-commit hook] Really want to commit into master? (Y/n) " yn
  if [ "$yn" = "" ]; then
    yn='Y'
  fi  
  case $yn in
      [Yy] ) exit 0; break;;
      [Nn] ) exit 1;; 
      * ) echo "Please answer y or n for yes or no.";;
  esac
done
```

(this snippet has been taken from a stackoverflow answer, the link to which I'll put later, in the comments section)

How do I do something like this with a pre-receive server side hook?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not put the link in the question?? Try to provide all information related to a question immediately.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to ask the user for input with a server side hook. It seems to be possible for client side hooks though. You could alternativly take a look at the pre push hook.

Comment: Is it to read user input in pre-commit git hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Zeeker suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405595/user-input-in-git-pre-receive-hook#comment39627507_25405595), you can't do this in a server hook: it has no input connection back to the user (said user may be using ssh to connect, via a git `ssh://` URL, but that ssh is not hooked to his or her keyboard in any way).

In the specific case of a pre-receive hook, the standard input is connected to a pipe,<sup>1</sup> the write end of which is connected to the command producing the *oldsha1 newsha1 refname* tuples (one per line).  An update hook has its standard input connected to `/dev/null` (or the moral equivalent, depending on system).  There is no controlling terminal, so opening `/dev/tty` is not possible either.

---

<sup>1</sup>I wrote a program that copies the pipe data to a temporary file and then runs one or more subsidiary hooks with the input coming from the temporary file, with its seek offset reset to 0 for each separate hook.  This allows using multiple hooks, any one of which can reject the update.  The pipe method is annoying since once one hook has consumed all the input, it cannot chain to a second hook, as the input is all gone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was kind of expecting that :-). Cant up vote since I dont have the requisite reputation.

Comment: @SakshamGupta You could mark the answer as correct.